# Prevent AutoExecute on modal window picker

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a screen with a "Modal Window Picker" for a field "Agent".  If the user clicks on it it will popup and allow the user to choose an agent.

But we have lots of agents and the user will always enter a search criteria for an agent.  How can I stop the initial load of the popup, it just takes time and is never useful?

Comment: As you know of the auto-execute option, please refine your problem. You don't know how to load/refresh the query results? You still need paging?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do what you want with the built-in MWP control, but my experience with MWP controls isn't that extensive, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Auto-execute is on the main window query but not an option on the modal popup window picker.  If it was then I could prevent the query running.  But this is what I would like to achieve.